# jQuery: split and hide html data

Tags: php, jquery

I need to split somehow some html data (a text with html tags) into two parts and hide the second one with a show/hide link.

The thing is all texts are being stored in the database with html tags. Some of those texts are short, but some are really long. We don't want't to show long ones, so one of the options is to show a teaser with a show/hide link. I can't just cut the string though (let's say first 300 characters), because it'll break html code of the page.

I'm looking for a solution/suggestions how to show a teaser of the text using jQuery without breaking the html code of the page.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you bring the data in the database for PHP with ajax or print / echo?

Comment: to start the second option is hidden?

Comment: yep, it should be hidden

Comment: you could put two pairs of parts or recodrs to see the HTML. thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [expader](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) ? looks like that is what your looking for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but html structure of those texts is random, so I can't use certain tag.